# Is there a way to open a tdms object in Python without reading a file from disk?

Tags: python

I'm given a byte array for a .tdms file and I need to read this data but from documentation `nptdms.read()` and `nptdms.open()` require a path to a file.

I could write the byte array to disk and use one of these methods but that seems inefficient.

Other than enhancing nptdms to accept a byte array and the solution I described above, do I have any good options?

Comment: From the docs, it can take either the path or an already opened file https://nptdms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apireference.html#nptdms.TdmsFile.read

Comment: @drum I saw that but I didn't think an "already opened file" and a byte array were the same thing. I'm pretty new with file i/o in Python.

Comment: can you give an example of how your byte array looks like?

Answer (score 1):

```
from io import BytesIO
from nptdms import TdmsFile

def tdms_bytearray_to_tdms_obj(tdms_bytearray):
  file_like_tdms = BytesIO(tdms_bytearray)
  return TdmsFile.read(file_like_tdms)
```

Comment: It would be useful if you put some explanation of it.